# How to remove TXT3 warnings in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

Almost crazy with such kind of warnings full in my arc lint response:

```
 Warning  (TXT3) Line Too Long
 This line is 94 characters long, but the convention is 80 characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the line length by adding something like this `"text.max-line-length": 120` to your .arclint file.  Our .arclint file looks like this to allow 120 characters:

```
{
    "linters": {
        "text": {
            "type": "text",
            "include": "(.md|.php$)",
            "exclude": "(vendor)",
            "text.max-line-length": 120
        },
        "spelling": {
            "type": "spelling",
            "include": "(.*)",
            "exclude": "(vendor)"
        },
        "phpcs": {
            "type": "phpcs",
            "include": "(\\.php$)",
            "bin": ["vendor/bin/phpcs", "phpcs"],
            "flags" : ["--standard=PSR1","--tab-width=2"],
            "severity.rules" : {
                "(^PHPCS\\.E\\.PSR1\\.Classes\\.ClassDeclaration\\.MissingNamespace)": "disabled"
            }
        },
        "generated" : {
            "type" : "generated",
            "include" : "(.*)"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you feel confident in changing the code behind Phabricator, you can make similar changes in the code: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_extending_lint/